# How to transform the following query into a jpa?

Tags: sql, jpa

```
(SELECT *
  FROM remedi.meds_donation
 WHERE state_short_name IN ('TN')
 AND request_date between "2018-10-01 00:55:48" AND "2018-11-29 13:02:14"
)
 union all
 (SELECT *
  FROM remedi.meds_donation
 WHERE state_short_name NOT IN ('TN')
 AND request_date between "2018-09-01 00:55:48" AND "2018-10-29 13:02:14"
)
 ORDER BY request_date DESC
```

Comment: "into a jpa" ? JPA is an API. You mean JPQL? In which case post the entities since JPQL uses entities/fields not tables/classes! And then post WHAT you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

The order by must be into the second or the union must be the subquery

Maybe you mean

```
SELECT * FROM (

(SELECT *
  FROM remedi.meds_donation
 WHERE state_short_name IN ('TN')
 AND request_date between "2018-10-01 00:55:48" AND "2018-11-29 13:02:14"
)
 union all
 (SELECT *
  FROM remedi.meds_donation
 WHERE state_short_name NOT IN ('TN')
 AND request_date between "2018-09-01 00:55:48" AND "2018-10-29 13:02:14"
)

) T ORDER BY request_date DESC
```

but I think is better

```
SELECT *
      FROM remedi.meds_donation
     WHERE state_short_name NOT IN ('TN')
     AND (request_date between "2018-09-01 00:55:48" AND "2018-10-29 13:02:14" or request_date between "2018-09-01 00:55:48" AND "2018-10-29 13:02:14") 
     ORDER BY request_date DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, but is not working for me, i want to order, first the rows where state_short_name is "TN" by request_date, after that order by request_date the rest of rows.

Comment: SELECT *
      FROM remedi.meds_donation
     WHERE state_short_name NOT IN ('TN')
     AND (request_date between "2018-09-01 00:55:48" AND "2018-10-29 13:02:14" or request_date between "2018-09-01 00:55:48" AND "2018-10-29 13:02:14") 
     ORDER BY state_short_name DESC, request_date DESC

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT *, (CASE WHEN state_short_name IN ('TN') then 0 else 1 END) as state_order
   FROM remedi.meds_donation
    WHERE request_date between "2018-10-01 00:55:48" AND "2018-11-29 13:02:14"
 ORDER BY state_order asc, request_date DESC
```